# Model access and creation in Cocoa Touch

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, model-view-controller, model, uiviewcontroller

I'm wondering what my options are for handing Model creation and how to access a model from ViewControllers? Assuming the application is non-trivial and a single Model needs to be shared amongst multiple ViewControllers, where should the Model be created and how should the ViewControllers access it?

There are numerous Actionscript frameworks that solve this problem using IOC/Dependency Injection or at worst Model Locator, but there seems to be nothing comparable in Cocoa Touch. From looking around at numerous code examples and projects it seems that most people do one of the following:

1. Declare their Models in the ApplicationDelegate and access them through that (Using it as a kind of registry that at least means the Models themselves don't have to be Singletons, but is ultimately hard to test and badly architected.
2. Have all their Models as Singletons (Bad for obvious reasons)
3. Pass models around between their ViewControllers which results in plenty of unnecessary code and can end up with some ViewControllers ferrying references to Models to other ViewControllers without actually needing to access them themselves.

Surely there is a better solution out there? It seems strange to me that the framework is so prescriptive over the intimate connection between UIViews and ViewControllers, yet offers no guidance or solution to hooking up the Model/Service tier. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of your model, Core Data is that missing "connection". Core Data makes it really easy to tie your model to your view controllers, and shuttle that data across to a view.

If you're not looking to use Core Data, probably the reason that no kind of model template is provided is because there's really nothing special about them - they simply store data. There are certain classes available that help you with the storing and disposal of data (see `NSCache`, for example), but aside from that your model classes could simply be an `NSObject` subclass with some public properties and/or custom accessors.

Using the AppDelegate as a kind of go-between sounds like a reasonable approach for accessing such objects if your application requires it, since your AppDelegate is readily accessible by any view controller. Although, unless it really doesn't make sense for your particular app, I would suggest that each view controller accesses the only the parts of the model that it needs. You can always make your view controller a delegate for a particular type of model data that can be accessed from 'further away', if required.

I hope that helps - sorry if I've misinterpreted the question!

Comment: Between CoreData, KVO and Notifications I am more than happy with the tools I have for authoring a Model and having it communicate with the rest of the application, but it is in the creation and access of the Model that it seems to break down. Using the AppDelegate as a kind of registry is convenient for sure, but that is not what it is for. And having a ViewController as delegate for a Model is just plain wrong. Thanks for taking the time to reply.

Comment: @1ndivisible: Why should using a view controller as a delegate in such a way be "plain wrong"? It is the role of the controller in the MVC design pattern to shuttle messages from the model to the view and vice versa. Defining a protocol for the controller is a convenient way to group together related methods for accessing model data. Out of interest, have you read through Apple's [Cocoa Design Patterns](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaDesignPatterns/CocoaDesignPatterns.html%23) reference ("The Model-View-Controller Design Pattern")?

Comment: Thanks for the link. That is a great document. Using a View Controller as a delegate is only wrong if the model is doing the delegating. A Model should know about nothing in the other application tiers. KVO and Notifications allow for this separation. To quote from the linked document: 'A Model class shouldn't depend on anything other than other Model classes.'

Comment: @1ndivisible: No problem. Yes, by making the view controller a delegate I was meaning just make it conform to a protocol that lists a group of accessors to the model. The model need not know anything about the delegation. By doing this you avoid sending references to the whole view controller interface to unrelated classes, instead providing only the interface relevant to the required parts of the model. I hope that makes sense.